# Как переписать код с axios?

Tags: reactjs

Используется реакт компонент [react-masonry-infinite](https://github.com/skoob13/react-masonry-infinite) 
Код такой:

```js
class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    elements: [],
    page: 1,
    limit: 20,
    total: 0,
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadThumbnails();
  }
 
  loadThumbnails = () => {
    const { page, limit } = this.state;
    
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      isError: false,
    }, () => {
      axios.get(
        `api/somePath?limit=${limit}&page=${page + 1}`
      ).then(response => {
        const { data: { elements, total } } = response;
      
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          elements: [
            ...prevState.elements,
            ...elements
          ],
          page: page + 1,
          isLoading: false,
          total,
        }));
      }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          isError: true,
        });
      });
    });
  };


  
  render() {
    const {
      elements,
      page,
      limit,
      total,
      isLoading,
    } = this.state;

    const hasMore = page * limit < total;

    return(
      <MasonryInfiniteScroller
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loadMore={this.loadThumbnails}
      >
        {elements.map(element => (
          <img
            key={element.id}
            src={element.thumbnail}
            style={{
              width: element.width + 'px',
              height: element.height + 'px',
            }}
          />
        ))}
        {isLoading && <div>...Loading</div>}
        {isError && (
          <div>
            Can't load data. Please, check your internet connection.
            <button onClick={this.loadThumbnails}>
              Try again
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </MasonryInfiniteScroller>
    ); 
  }
}
```

Вопросы вызывает функция loadThumbnails:
1) Какой адрес прописать в axios.get, если необходимо, чтобы на страницчку подгружались изображения? 
2) Что означает этот код: 
...prevState.elements,
...elements

Answer (score 0):

Первый ответ.

В `axios.get(url)` - вы должны передать url, к которому обратится приложение, и обращение обработается на сервере. Сервер должен по этому запросу вернуть список путей к картинкам.

Второй ответ.

```
elements: [
   ...prevState.elements,
   ...elements
],
```

Здесь используется [Оператор расширения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).
В данном случае - набор старых элементов конкатенируется с набором новопришедших элементов с сервера.